# Simple HTML DOM Parser crashes

Tags: php, memory-leaks, simple-html-dom

When you load a large HTML page into simple_html_dom it crashes. when I parse [Washington](http://www.cityvibe.com/lasvegas/Escorts/) url it works but when I parse [las vegas](http://www.cityvibe.com/lasvegas/Escorts/) it's doesn't work and It shows this error.

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /var/www/html/city2.php on line 20`

Here is the code

```
<?php

function httpGet($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
//  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$url="http://www.cityvibe.com/lasvegas/Escorts/";
$parse=httpGet($url);
$html = str_get_html($parse);
for ($y = 0; $y <= 10; $y++) {
$ret = $html->find('.image-link',$y)->href;
$rep=str_replace("//","http://",$ret);
$esc=httpGet($rep);
$grep=str_get_html($esc);
$ret2 = $grep->find('.post-name',0)->innertext;
echo $ret2;
?>
```

I have tried to fix the memory leak but it's still not working

[PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser Memory Leak / Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090212/php-simple-html-dom-parser-memory-leak-usage)

any way to fix this?

Comment: Either `$html` or `$grep` isn't a simplehtmldom object, and you simply assumed that you'd always find a match in the DOM. never assume success when dealing with external resources. always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: start basic debugging: `var_dump($html, $get)` and see what the html looks like. just because it works for one page means absolutely nothing for another. it's a dynamically generated page and can be TOTALLY different with only minor changes in the url.

Comment: yes you are right @MarcB , I am using the same script for washington and that works but there is something wrong with lasvegas, I have seen the output for like 2 times after that it showing that error.

Comment: so go look at the fetched lasvegas html. you'll undoubtedly find that it DOESN'T contain that `.image-link` or `.post-name` class.

Comment: check this out 
https://s31.postimg.org/53wbm9ct7/class.png

it does contain image-link class

Comment: the problem is in line 20, that the str_file_html is not loading the html, when I echo $html, there is no output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115343/discussion-between-n-b-sri-harsha-and-marc-b).

Comment: you have to build in a better way of identifying if `$html->find('.image-link',$y)->href;` is an object, e.g. `if($html->find('.image-link',$y)->href;) {`. I use simple html dom and it's great however there are times when the page won't load and the script will fail, or when the page author changes the  page code. I have set my script up in such a way that if I the object can't be found, an email is sent to me. Also why don't you change your `curl_setopt` to include `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`?

Comment: It's a bug. For PHP5 consider [this replacement](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom)

Comment: @pguardiario It solved my problem, thanks. I'm guessing because this version has a reduced memory requirement. Also very easy to install: no dependencies.